# Having IApplicationBuilder in .NET Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, owin

I apologize if this isn't architecturally possible,
but I'm just trying to integrate certain .NET Core features
into my existing old Webforms application, as I would someday like
to move to .NET Core, but I don't want to continue writing
outdated code.

Anyways, when using `Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb`
my application requires a Startup Class.
However it expects a method: `Configuration(IAppBuilder app)`,
but the features I am looking for (e.g. `app.UseMvc()`) require
`app` to be of `IApplicationBuilder`.

Could one to hackishly convert a `IAppBuilder` to `IApplicationBuilder`?
I'd imagine if such a thing were possible,
it would require bringing in a few other classes.

Or even better, is there a Package similair to `SystemWeb` that looks for
a Startup class but instead expects `Configure(Iapplicationbuilder app, ...)`.

It seems somewhat outlandish, but it would be nice to be able to do,
and if anyone knows how to do such a thing, it would be here.

Comment: Are you trying to add ASP.NET Core to an ASP.NET application? Or ASP.NET code to an ASP.NET Core application? You won't be able to get any of the options to work, but there is OWIN support in ASP.NET Core.

Comment: Preferably, ASP.NET Core into an ASP.NET Application. I was aware of OWIN support in ASP.NET Core. Also, I have had mild success running ASP.NET core as an async process inside of a ASP.NET application, as well as targeting 4.6 from  .NET Core. You're right that both solutions left a lot to be desired.

Comment: So you are running ASP.NET as a reverse proxy to ASP.NET Core? Isn't that extremely inefficient? They are entirely different frameworks, I wouldn't attempt to mix them like this.

Comment: Basically, that's one of the many reasons why I gave up on that solution.

Comment: One option you could investigate is [Integrating ASP.NET Core With Webforms Using IIS URL Rewrite](http://geekswithblogs.net/mrsteve/archive/2017/03/25/run-asp-net-core-mvc-alongside-webforms-iis-url-rewrite.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

ASP.NET Core and ASP.NET are fundamentally incompatible. You cannot mix and match ASP.NET Core and something like Web Forms. Period. There's is no partial upgrade support. Moving an existing ASP.NET app to ASP.NET Core is all or nothing.